# Angular 2 custom data validation - changing style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I'm trying to use a validator to change color based on the input values in the number input. I have several different ranges that should correspond to different colors. I use different validators for each range. Here is an example of one of them:

```
// Validation for scanid
  volumeValidationRange1(controls) {
    var vol = controls.value;
    if (vol > 10.0 && vol <= 20.0) {
      // controls.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
      document.getElementById('123').style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
      return { 'volumeValidationRange1': true } // Return error in validation
    } else {
      return null; // return valid
    }
  }
```

It works when I use `document.getElementById('123').style.backgroundColor = 'orange';`, but `controls.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';` does not work. controls is of type `FormControl`. Is there a way to change style using `FormControl`?

Comment: Did you try using [style.background-color]="yourColor" or [ngClass]="yourColor"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I would like it to be generalized, because I need to use this validation in few places and don't want to create a validator for each input field...

Comment: Is it angular 2 or Angular JS?

Comment: it is angular 2

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access any style through FormControls' methods and properties.
 In this case, only DOM elements have this property.
You can check properties and methods instantiated in contructor: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl